# How to compare the data between two query results from SQL Server and DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2, database-migration

As part of a migration project I need to test the data in the source database (in SQL Server) with the target database (in DB2).

Some of the columns from the source are mapped to the target tables. The source database has millions of rows and I need to confirm the data is properly migrated.

How can I compare the data resulting from SQL queries on both the source and target databases?

Please provide some solution.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server you can link to DB2 using the Linked Server feature, then you can execute some queries against both servers or even joining them in a same query. Be aware of the cost (network, disks, memory...). You will have to perform some performance tests.

See how to link the servers:

[Creating a linked server to DB2 using Microsoft OLE DB provider for DB2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222937)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will check the option and update the outcome

Answer (score 0):

As @Caffe said, you can link both databases. From DB2 you can do that by Federation. However, this option is not included in the basic installation, and you should use Information Integration (that is not the last name, it changed recently).